# extract a column in dataframe based on condition for another column R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to extract a column from a dataframe in R based on a condition for another column in the same dataframe, the dataframe is given below.

```
b <- c(1,2,3,4)
g <- c("a", "b" ,"b", "c")
df <- data.frame(b,g)
row.names(df) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc" , "dd")
```

I want to extract all values for column b as a dataframe (with rownames) where column g has value 'b',

My required output is given below:

```
df
   b
cc 3
dd 4
```

I have tried several methods like `which` or `subset` but it does not work. I have also tried to find the answer to this question on stackoverflow but I was not able to find it. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean `subset(df, g == 'b', select = b)` Or `df %>%filter(g == 'b') %>%select(b)` in `dplyr` ? The values for `g = 'b'` is 2, 3 and not 3, 4.

Comment: @RonakShah thanks this is exactly what I wanted, could you please post it as answer so I accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `subset` function in base R -

```
subset(df, g == 'b', select = b)

#   b
#bb 2
#cc 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic way of slicing data in r

```
df[df$g == 'b',]['b']
```

Or the tidyverse answer

```
df %>%
  filter(g == 'b') %>%
  select(b)
```

Comment: ```df[df$g == 'b', 'b']```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = 'g')['b', .(b)]
   b
1: 2
2: 3
```

---

Or with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
sbt(df, g == 'b', b)
  b
1 2
2 3
```